# Get folder and subfolder id Google Drive

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I want to retrieve all ids from the folders and the subfolders from my Google Drive Account. I am using the [work with folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) from Google Drive Rest API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy. Use [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) and in the "`search`" field, place `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder` as the parameter to indicate that you're only looking for files of type folder. Execute that and it will return all your folder. Indicate in the fields that you're looking for "id". You'll have the complete list of your folder IDs.

Run this [API Explorer URL](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?q=mimeType+%253D+'application%252Fvnd.google-apps.folder'&fields=files%252CincompleteSearch%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken&_h=5&) to see for yourself. I've already placed the necessary fields for you. Just Execute and Authorize. Just look for the `id` property, that's it.